# RGA package Lexical Error

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, segments

I am using RGA to extract Google Analytics data into R. I am having difficulties with segments that have spaces. When running this code everything works fine:

```
kw <- "iPhone"
seg <- paste('sessions::condition::ga:searchKeyword=@',kw,sep="")
data <- ga$getData(ids, start.date="2014-12-14", end.date="2014-12-14", 
                   metrics = "ga:sessions", dimensions = "", 
                   sort = "", filters = "", segment = seg)
```

But when running this code (only difference is in kw):

```
kw <- "iPhone 6"
seg <- paste('sessions::condition::ga:searchKeyword=@',kw,sep="")
data <- ga$getData(ids, start.date="2014-12-14", end.date="2014-12-14", 
                   metrics = "ga:sessions", dimensions = "", 
                   sort = "", filters = "", segment = seg)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in parseJSON(txt) : lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang=en> 
                     (right here) ------^
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the string you are sending in seg needs to be HTML encoded

`iPhone` 6  vs  `iPhone%206`

The error message that it cant parse the JSon I think it because its returning a HTML error message to you.  You can test segments here [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/)

Sorry I don't know R I just just worked extensively with the Google Analytics API